# What does '~にゃい' mean?

Tags: verbs, slang

What does the 'にゃい' mean in the phrase '働きたくにゃい' or 'はたらきたくにやい'? (not sure if it's a small ya or not). It's in a line sticker.

Answer (score 12):

「[働]{はたら}きたくにゃい」 is just a cute way of saying 「働きたくない」.　It makes you sound like a kitten speaking.

Comment: Whether or not that's cute depends on who you are right?

Comment: Although typically used by teenager girls in manga/anime, I won't be surprised to see my male friends in their thirties sporadically use this in Twitter, etc, unless they're severe otaku haters. Meow.