# はずかぴー という意味は？教えてください

Tags: i-adjectives

はずかぴーという言葉聞いたんですけど
意味はあまりわかりません
はずかぴーと恥ずかしいは何の違いがありますか？

Comment: どこで聞きましたか？分脈教えたら助かります。

Comment: 日本バンドAcid Black CherryさんのDVDから聞きました（╹◡╹）

Comment: I think this might be an [autological](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word) word.

Comment: @snailplane Are you referring to ピー音 for bleep censor? I don't think that's relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same as 恥ずかしい but said weirdly in the hope of sounding cute or funny, in the same vein as [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15106/5010).

This method (adding ぴ everywhere replacing い and other letters) was intensively used by [Noriko Sakai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noriko_Sakai) almost 30 years ago (known as [のりピー語](http://norip.55street.net/z.html)), and somehow it's still used by some people. If used properly by a real young person, it may sound funny, but usually this is considered cheesy "oyaji gag" now. If you're still learning Japanese, perhaps you can make Japanese people laugh with this word, but please don't overuse it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just sounds like a playful version of はずかしい.

Comment: みんなありがとうございました